# CSS hover effect doesn't work in Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, hover

I have a hover effect pure CSS and it works fine with Chrome and Opera but doesn't work in Firefox. It's white and when you hover you see the after effect image.

Here is the snippet with the HTML and CSS code.

```css
.hovereffect {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  float: left;
  overflow: hidden;
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  cursor: default;
}

.hovereffect .overlay {
  position: absolute;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 80%;
  height: 80%;
  left: 10%;
  top: 10%;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #FFF;
  border-top: 1px solid #FFF;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: scale(0,1);
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  -ms-transform: scale(0,1);
  transform: scale(0,1);
}

.hovereffect:hover .overlay {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: scale(1);
    -moz-transform: scale(1);
  -ms-transform: scale(1);
  transform: scale(1);
}

.hovereffect img {
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-transition: all 0.35s;
    -moz-transition: all 0.35s;
  transition: all 0.35s;
}

.hovereffect:hover img {
  filter: url('data:image/svg+xml;charset=utf-8,<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"><filter id="filter"><feComponentTransfer color-interpolation-filters="sRGB"><feFuncR type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncG type="linear" slope="0.6" /><feFuncB type="linear" slope="0.6" /></feComponentTransfer></filter></svg>#filter');
  filter: brightness(0.6);
  -webkit-filter: brightness(0.6);
    -moz-filter: brightness(0.6);
}

.hovereffect h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
  text-align: center;
  position: relative;
  font-size: 17px;
  background-color: transparent;
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
    -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
     -moz-transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,-100%,0);
}

.hovereffect a, hovereffect p {
  color: #FFF;
  padding: 1em 0;
  opacity: 0;
  filter: alpha(opacity=0);
  -webkit-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
     -moz-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;
  transition: opacity 0.35s, transform 0.35s;
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,100%,0);
}

.hovereffect:hover a, .hovereffect:hover p, .hovereffect:hover h2 {
  opacity: 1;
  filter: alpha(opacity=100);
  -webkit-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
    -moz-transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
  transform: translate3d(0,0,0);
}
```

```html
 <div class="hovereffect">
                <a href="http://pmtsit.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/02/500x300.gif">
         <img class="img-responsive center-block" src="http://pmtsit.com/wp- content/uploads/2015/02/500x300.gif" alt="dare">
            <div class="overlay">
                <h1>Dare  </h1>
                
    <p> 
     
                        <h3bla bla
                        </h3>
    </p> 
            </div>
                </a>
        </div>
```

Comment: Don't you have to use `-moz-transform` too, along with `-moz-transition`?

Comment: Firefox is the browser. Mozilla is the organization that develops it.

Comment: ..and FF doesn't require prefixes on transforms or animations any more but you can't mix `-moz` and `-webkit` like is being done here.

Comment: So how can I solve this? I didn't catch the solution.

Comment: @user3247715 have you corrected errors such as `-moz-transition: opacity 0.35s, -webkit-transform 0.35s;`? Also, the snippet doesn't work because of the space in the url to the image.